# How to add a shown event in user control

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls

I have a user control that i have to add a shown event or there is another event for user control which behaves like shown event of windows form.

Comment: Reference: http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/489987/AddplusShownpluseventplustoplusaplusUserControlplu

Comment: I have used that code but that is not execute

Comment: What do you think of this - using Load event and disposing the form on Closing event (so that Load gets called next time). That way, would you get the same behaviour as Shown event?

Answer (score 9):

You can fake your own shown method by using the Paint event of the usercontrol:

```
public UserControl1() {
  InitializeComponent();
}

public event EventHandler Shown;
private bool wasShown = false;

protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e) {
  base.OnPaint(e);
  if (!wasShown) {
    wasShown = true;
    if (Shown != null) {
      Shown(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
  }
}
```